# Store invalid JSON columns are STRING or skip them in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ndjson

I have a JSON data file which looks something like below

```
{
    "key_a": "value_a",
    "key_b": "value_b",
    "key_c": {
        "c_nested/invalid.key.according.to.bigquery": "valid_value_though"
    }
}
```

As we know BigQuery considers ***c_nested/invalid.key.according.to.bigquery*** as an invalid column name. I have a huge amount of log data exported by StackDriver into Google Cloud Storage which has a lot of invalid fields (according to BigQuery `Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long).`

As a workaround, I am trying to store the value to the `key_c` (the whole  `{"c_nested/invalid.key.according.to.bigquery": "valid_value_though"}` thing) as a string in the BigQuery table.

I presume my table definition would look something like below:

```
[
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "key_a", 
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "key_b", 
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "key_c", 
        "type": "STRING"
    }
]
```

When I try to create a table with this schema I get the below error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.

Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0

Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Expected key
```

Assuming it is now supported in BigQuery, I thought of simply skipping the `key_c` column with the below schema:

```
[
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "key_a", 
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "key_b", 
        "type": "STRING"
    }
]
```

The above schema lets me at least create a permanent table (for querying external data), but when I am trying to query the data I get the following error:

```
Error while reading table: 
projectname.dataset_name.table_name, error message: 
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: No such field: key_c.
```

I understand there is a way described [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6) to *load each JSON row raw to BigQuery - as if it was a CSV - and then parse in BigQuery* but hat makes the queries too complicated.

Is cleaning the data the only way? How can I tackle this?

I am looking for a way to skip making a column for invalid fields and store then directly as STRING or simply ignore them fully. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main premise why people use BQ (and other cloud databases) is that storage is cheap.  In practice, it is often helpful to load 'raw' or 'source' data into BQ and then transform it as needed (views or other transformation tools).  This is a paradigm shift from `ETL` to `ELT`.

With that in mind, I would import your "invalid" JSON blob as a string, and then parse it in your transformation steps.  Here is one method:

```
 with data as (select '{"key_a":"value_a","key_b":"value_b","key_c":{"c_nested/invalid.key.according.to.bigquery":"valid_value_though"}}' as my_string)
select 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(my_string,'$.key_a') as key_a,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(my_string,'$.key_b') as key_b,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(my_string,"c_nested/invalid.key.according.to.bigquery","custom_key"),'$.key_c.custom_key') as key_c
from data
```

Comment: per OP - "I am looking for a way to skip making a column for invalid fields and store then directly as STRING or simply ignore them fully" ! just in case if you missed that part

Comment: This explains how to query data into Bigquery. Would you mind explaining how to put data into Bigquery considering these invalid fields? I would prefer not loading the data into stackdriver but Creating and external table keeping the data into Google cloud storage but querying it in Bigquery. [here's](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources) how gcp explains this process.

Comment: Totally understand.  To answer your specific question: `Is this possible?`, then the answer is "probably".  I am an analyst by trade, so i am generally trying to 'Get Stuff Done', so I prefer to opt for easy, tested solutions (also learning a lot from Mickhail's answers).  If you are looking at this problem as a data engineering/pipeline/google-cloud problem, then my suggestion is probably not optimal in this case, and fair enough.  The question has a BigQuery tag, and I provided a BigQuery solution.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant would you be able to tell if what I am trying to explain in my question is possible (or the best approach to handle this situation)?